# How to solve error " Invalid token. invalid request BLR at offset 2. function FFILTERNUMERIC is not defined."

Tags: firebird

Invalid token.
invalid request BLR at offset 2. function FFILTERNUMERIC is not defined. module name or entrypoint could not be found.

someone can help me?

I need this table but I can't see

Comment: There must be some UDF library which implements this function. Execute the following statement SELECT * FROM rdb$functions. You will see what the library file name is. If you transfered the database file from another server, look into the UDF subfolder of the Firebird main folder. Library's DLL should be there. Just copy it to your server.